# Write a string with caption method using MiniMagick

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, minimagick

I'm trying to write a string over a image. Currently I'm using MiniMagick and I can resize and overlap two images, but when I try write a multiline string using caption nothing happens to final image, it's still same as before.

Here is my current code:

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.open('template.jpg')
image.combine_options do |c|
  c.background '#0008'
  c.fill '#666'
  c.gravity 'center'
  c.size '100x50'
  c.caption "Lets write some big string here... zzzzz I hope this work =)"
end
image.write('final.jpg')
```

My refs:
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/

[ImageMagick multiline text and background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353401/imagemagick-multiline-text-and-background-image)

http://www.imagemagick.org/www/command-line-options.html#caption

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended using a system call to get rid this problem, here is the code:

```
Subexec.run "convert -background '#fff0' \\
  -fill '#003300' \\
  -gravity west \\
  -size 560x180 \\
  -pointsize 19 \\
  -font \'#{font_path}\' \\
  caption:\"#{caption}\" \\
  #{photo_path} \\
  +swap \\
  -gravity NorthWest \\
  -geometry +333+113 \\
  -composite #{photo_path}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Convert with MiniMagick. And caption is great because it will wrap and adjust according to the size, as long as you don't put in `pointsize`. The syntax is a little tricky though because there aren't many Rails examples out there.

```
file = Paperclip::Tempfile.new(["processed", ".jpg"])

MiniMagick::Tool::Convert.new do |img|
  img.background '#0008'
  img.fill '#666'
  img.gravity 'center'
  img.size '100x50'
  img << "caption: Lets write some big string here... zzzzz I hope this work =)"
  img << file.path
 end

model.picture = file
model.save
file.unlink
```

Note: You have to add file path last